# Next Js getInitialProps within a component not passing props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have having a rather frustrating time with Next Js and am hoping that someone will be able to help.

We have a component and I am trying to use "getInitialProps" to pass props to a component during the server-side rending process, however, nothing seems to come through. I'm pretty sure I've tried every permeation I can think of and the props never go through. I know that the getInitialProps is being fired because I see the console.log coming through in the command line.

```
const HeaderMain = (props) => {
   return(
      <>
         <h1>props.name</h1> <!-- This is blank -->
      </>
   );
};

HeaderMain.getInitialProps = async ({ req }) => {
   console.log({ req: req }) // this works
   // Do some other stuff here
   return { 
      name: "Paul"
   }
}

export default HeaderMain
```

If anyone could give me a point in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe a copy/paste mistake but you're missing the closing bracket (`}`) in your `getInitialProps` function.

Comment: Thanks, it was a typo. Fixed now.

Comment: Do you have a custom `_app` page by any chance? If so, could you add the code for it to the question?

Comment: In the end we just decided to send the data to the component through props sent form the main page; it feels hacky but it works.

Comment: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/getInitialProps#caveats
did you see "can not be used in children components", isn't this your case? If so, passing props can't be hacky because it's official way :)

Comment: I didn't say it was hacky, just that it feels that way :) Than again a lot in this React / NextJS works feels really counterintuitive and hacky to me. Than again, what do I know, I'm a dinosaur :)

Comment: Server side functions support only on page components in NextJS. If your component is descendent of page component then define the server side logic on parent and write your code.

Answer (score -1):

In the end, we have decided to send the data from the main page through props to the component. It took quite a bit of digging around to see how the rendering engine works to get it to work the way we wanted it to work.